# Link to PR2/Startrobot is down

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the tutorial on this page:
http://wiki.ros.org/2dnav_pr2_app/Tutorials/RunningNavigationStack

As it says, I need to follow the steps according to this link:
http://pr.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2/StartRobot

The problem is that the link isn't working. Normaly this isn't a problem, but I don't know whats written on that page.
Does someone knows how I can acces this page via another route? Or does someone has another solution?
Please let me know.

Kind regards,
Bert

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217496/link-to-pr2/startrobot-is-down/) by [Burcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/23838/burcks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if it's exactly the same, but this tutorial should contain similar information: http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_robot/Tutorials/Starting%20up%20the%20PR2

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1